# Create and Run Multiple Solver Instances in Parallel

Tags: drake

I'd like to run multiple solvers in multiple threads and eventually processes. I'm currently running a for-loop and creating threads like the following:

```
for (...) {
    pthread_t pid;
    Args args;
    args.solver = solver???
    pthread_create(&pid, NULL, &func, (void*)&args);
}
```

When defining `solver`, I've tried several options, though none have worked.

First, I tried calling `const auto solver = drake::solvers::MakeSolver(solver_id);`, then passing `solver.get()` into each thread's args. This successfully compiles and runs, but I get some obscure failure `terminate called recursively` in `drake::solvers::SnoptSolver::DoSolve`. I saw that MakeSolver seems to return a unique ptr around a single solver instance defined in `kKnownSolvers`, so possibly the threads are calling `DoSolve` on the same solver instance, causing this issue.

I then tried creating multiple instances of the solver. Calling `StaticSolverInterface::Make<SnoptSolver>()` didn't work since that is defined in an unnamed namespace and thus is only accessible in that file. Calling `const auto solver = drake::solvers::MakeSolver(solver_id);` and copying the `SolverInterface` pointed to by `solver` isn't possible because `SolverInterface` is not movable or copyable.

Is what I'm doing possible? If so, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `drake::solvers::MakeSolver(solver_id)` multiple times and giving each one to a different thread should work fine.  It returns distinct objects each time, nothing is shared.

Similarly, repeated calls to `make_unique<SnoptSolver>` or the like should also work, if you can hard-code which solver you'd like instead of going by the `id`.

The `terminate` error message is probably an unhandled exception.  Generally when you make a thread you'll want to put a `try { } catch () {}` within the immediate entry point; you don't want exceptions to leave the thread.

Also I strongly suggest `std::thread` if you're in C++; the pthread API is old and stinky.

Comment: I see, I realized I was creating new diagram and plant contexts in the for-loop and those were going out of scope. I'll add those try and catch statements so this doesn't happen. What's weird is that using ```auto solver = std::make_shared<drake::solvers::SnoptSolver>()``` showed the errors properly, but it doesn't matter. Thanks!